# Why should I create android icon for different device sizes?

Tags: android, icons

All I do is scale image using GIMP and put them into hdpi, ldpi and mdpi. Is there a good reason for bundling icons of all different sizes into the package, since I do not correct the pixels after resizing?

Comment: -1 as this topic has been covered many times on SO and there is plenty of documentation for this exact topic at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you don't export your vector images into your icon files directly to have the best quality, resizing them in Gimp is still better than just using one icon in your project, because the scaling of a dedicated image processor (like Gimp2) will always be better than what Android can do natively for you.

Answer (score 1):

In android we have a tool called NinePatch here we use a single image for all the type of screen resolution. just you need to create an image using Ninepatch tool. The NinePatch image will have an extension .9.png
In Android we have phones of different resloution and a single app/code we develop supports multi resolution in order to maintain in the image clarity we need to have images in hdpi,mdpi,ldpi

Answer (score 0):

If you scale down from a higher resolution then it's ok.

But if you scale up from a lower resolution then it will just look bad on those devices.